# How to print and separate key and values from Nested Json array angular 2 and add it in a a select box

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, typescript

I'm having a Json data model from that i want to fetch the data and add it into a select box as my drop down items. 
While doing that I'm facing difficulties to fetch the data to the select box .
Iterations are working fine. but the whole Json array is getting printed. I want only my 3 Major Headings to be get printed.

Error Message:-**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

I'm adding my sample Json and expected output also

Expected Output

LEED V4 BD+C
LEED V4 ID+C
LEED V4 EBOM

**Sample Json**

```
{
    "Ratings": {
        "LEED V4 BD+C": [{

        }],
        "LEED V4 ID+C": [{

        }],
        "LEED V4 EBOM": [{

        }]
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
 template: `
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
               <label class="control-label">Rating System <span style="color: #2196f3;">*</span></label>
                <select class="form-control" id="productparameter" *ngFor="let item of ratings.Ratings" >
                <option value="">Select Rating</option>
                <option value="">{{item}}</option>
              </select>
              </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
 public ratings: any ={
    "Ratings": {
        "LEED V4 BD+C": [{

        }],
        "LEED V4 ID+C": [{

        }],
        "LEED V4 EBOM": [{

        }]
    }
}
  constructor( ) {

    console.log( this.ratings.Ratings);

  }
```

adding my plunker link :-https://plnkr.co/edit/pgbeS9iRkAzgWVNrLNQJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first thing is that you need to use the `ngFor`in your `option` instead of the `select` box itself.

```
<select class="form-control" id="productparameter"  >
   <option value="">Select Rating</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of elements" value="">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

And you can declare an `array` in your component model which will take the `Object.keys(this.ratings.Ratings)` where all the possible keys will be stored.

```
public elements: any = Object.keys(this.ratings.Ratings);
```

Then use this new `array` in your `ngFor` like this:

```
*ngFor="let item of elements"
```

This is [your updated **Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/17NtGlZ4o0ZbVYqFc87J?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

i am not getting what u want to display but i tried :

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, ChangeDetectorRef,Pipe} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Rating System <span style="color: #2196f3;">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="productparameter">
            <option value="">Select Rating</option>
            <option value="" *ngFor="let rat of rating">{{rat}}</option>
          </select>
          </div>`,
   })

  export class App {

     public rating : any = ["LEED V4 BD+C":["One"],"LEED V4 ID+C":["two"],"LEED V4 EBOM":["Three"]]
    constructor( ) {}

  }

 @NgModule({
   imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
   declarations: [ App ],
   bootstrap: [ App ]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

its output will be :

[image]